# Fullscreen google map with Polymer

Tags: google-maps, polymer-1.0

i'am trying to make a map using Polymer element (google-map), it's working when i use the style like `height: 100px` but i want to make it fullscreen.

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<!-- Maps Element -->
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/google-map/google-map.html">

<script src="../../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dom-module id="geo-maps">

    <template>
        <style>
            google-map {
                display: block; 
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
            }
        </style>

        <google-map latitude="37.77493" longitude="-122.41942"></google-map>

    </template>


    <script>
        Polymer({
          is: 'geo-maps',
          properties: {
          }
        });
    </script>

</dom-module>
```

that is my code, i try some link on Github and other site but it been removed, its there something i missing.?

for now i use this

```
<style>
       google-map {
           display: block; 
           height: 70vw;
           width: 84vw;
       }
</style>
```

if you have more perfect code for fullscreen that will help.

Answer (score 1):

This will fill up the window. Hope this helps

```
google-map {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but that not work for me, with 100vh some content are overflow, with 90vh it's fit, but when the screen size get small it have blank space.